# How do I convert coordinates to a Latitude & Longitude?

Tags: gis, latitude-longitude

I am reverse engineering a transportation visualization app. I need to find out the latitude for the origin of their data feed. Specifically what XY 0,0 is. The only formulas I have found calculate distance between two points, or location of a bearing/distance.

They use the XY to display a map in a very legacy application. The XY is in FEET.

I have these coordinates:

```
47.70446615506108, -122.34469839507263: x=1268314, y=260622
47.774182540800616,-122.3412994737105:  x=1269649, y=286031
47.60024792289405, -122.32767331735774: x=1271767, y=222532
47.57012494413499, -122.29129609983679: x=1280532, y=211374
```

I need to find out what the latitude and longitude of `x=0, y=0` is and what the formula would be to find this out.

They have two data feeds, one is more current than the other. The feed with the most current data does NOT include latitude, longitude, but only XY. I am trying to extrapolate based on their less current, yet more informative (includes lat, lon) data feed what 0,0 is so I can simply convert their (more current) data feed's XY coordinates to latitude and longitude.

Comment: why your x values are not negative when you have negative longitude?

Comment: This is a very confusing question.  Are X and Y distances North and South from the given lat/lon point?

Comment: ... or are the lat/long map coordinates, and x/y are coordinates on some huge bitmap?

Comment: Thanks for the points. I have added more verbosity to my question.

Comment: It also depends on the level of accuracy you require.

Comment: Postive 47 degrees is North latitude, while -122 longitude would be West

Comment: I removed the "not-programming-related" tag since this is essential in writing a GIS app, working with Google Maps, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ask them what coordinate system they're using! (or if you got the dataset from some database, look at the metadata for the dataset and it should tell you. Otherwise I'd be skeptical of its value)

Most likely this is one of the [state plane coordinate systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_Plane_Coordinate_System). They're for localized areas of the earth (kind of like [UTM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system)), and are frequently used for surveying.

You can use [CORPSCON](http://crunch.tec.army.mil/software/corpscon/corpscon.html) (or other GIS programs; [ExpertGPS](http://www.expertgps.com/) will do this if you have the GIS Option Pack but it's not free. I forget whether [GPSBabel](http://www.gpsbabel.org/) does conversion) to convert between lat/long and any of the state plane coordinate systems. You'll also need to know which [datum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datum_(geodesy)) the coordinates are in. WGS84 and NAD83 are very close but NAD27 is different.

Comment: +1 for being US specific, since the OP gave lat-long in Seattle. The highest-voted more general answer is still good since some of us dwell elsewhere ;)

Answer (score 9):

If you look at the first 2 lines of data, and subtract the latitude

```
47.7044 - 47.7741 = -0.06972 degrees
```

There are 60 nautical miles per degree of latitude, and 6076 feet per nautical mile.

```
-.06972 * 60 * 6076 = 25,415 ft
```

Subtracting the two 'Y' values:

```
260662 - 286031 = 25,409 ft
```

So indeed that seems to prove the X and Y values are in feet.

If you take any of the Y values, and convert back to degrees, for example

```
260622 ft / ( 6076 ft/nm ) / ( 60 nm/degree ) = .71
286031 ft / 6076 / 60 = .78
```

So subtracting those values from the latitudes of (47.70 and 47.77) gives you very close to exactly 47 degrees, which should be your y=0 point.

For longitude, a degree is 60 nautical miles at the equator and 0 miles at the poles. So the number of miles per degree has to be multiplied by the cosine of the latitude, so approx cos(47 degrees), or .68.  So instead of 6076 nm per degree, it's about 4145 nm.

So for the X values,

```
1268314 ft / ( 4145 ft/nm ) / ( 60 nm/degree ) = 5.10 degrees
1269649 ft / 4145 / 60 = 5.10 degrees
```

These X numbers increase as the latitude increases (less negative), so I believe you should add 5.1 degrees, which means the X base point is about

```
-122.3 + 5.1 = 117.2 West longitude for your x=0 point.
```

This is roughly the position of Spokane WA.

So given X=1280532, Y=211374

```
Lat = 47 + ( 211374 / 6096 / 60 ) = 47.58
Lon = -117.2 - ( 1280532 / ( 6096 * cos(47.58)) / 60 ) = -122.35
```

Which is roughly equivalent to the given data 47.57 and -122.29

The variance may be due to different projections - the X,Y system may be a "flattened" projection as opposed to lat/long which apply to a spherical projection?  So to be accurate you may yet need more advanced math or that open source library :)

This question may also be helpful, it contains code for calculating great circle distances:

[Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points/215849#215849)

Comment: This back-of-envelope stuff will be OK if the domain isn't very large and you don't need very high accuracy

Comment: Yes, for now just trying to make sense of the data.  It is fairly basic math involved, calculating great circle distances.

Comment: I really would not recommend this approach, it's really quite surprising how large the errors are on the ground if the proper calculation isn't used.

Comment: Just trying to help him understand the data and where the x=0, y=0 point might be.  As MarkJ said, back of the envolope stuff.

Answer (score 6):

There are many different coordinate systems. You need to find out the what the coordinate systems are for both the lat/lon's (e.g. WGS84 etc) and x/y's first (e.g. some sort of projected system probably).

Once you have that information there are several tools you can use to do conversions and manipulations. One example (of a free open source coding library) is [proj4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/).

Comment: I used Proj.4 for something like this -- highly recommended.

Comment: More pedantry, but isn't proj4 a command-line tool rather than a coding library? (Obviously you can shell it from code)

Comment: MarkJ: it's both. we're using it as a library and it's excellent.

Answer (score 1):

You've got good advice on coordinate systems already, so I'll just chime in with the library I've used with great success in the past.

Geotrans is approved for use by the US Department of Defence, so you can be sure that it is well tested.  You can grab it from here:

```
http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/geotrans/index.html
```

That might not be the right link as that page talks about the application, not the library.  I expect the library is in the Developers package.  Licensing terms were very liberal from memory, but make sure you review the terms before using it commercially.

Edit:

An interesting discussion on Geotrans licensing can be found here:

```
http://www.mail-archive.com/debian-legal@lists.debian.org/msg39263.html
```

Answer (score 0):

[Over here, I said this:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753560/how-to-convert-utm-coordinates-to-latitude-and-longitude/753609#753609)

In Java, I would use the [OpenMap converter](http://openmap.bbn.com/doc/api/com/bbn/openmap/proj/coords/UTMPoint.html#toLatLonPoint()) from a point's expression in UTM to one using Latitude and Longitude (assuming a WGS-84 ellipsoid which is most commonly used in GPS).

OpenMap is open source and I would post a link to their download page but they have a short license script in the way.  So, to avoid being rude, I won't deep link.  Instead, head to [their homepage](http://openmap.bbn.com/) and [click Downloads](http://openmap.bbn.com/cgi-bin/license.cgi).

That should either solve your problem directly or at least point you towards a useful algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Brenor Brophey's [gPoint PHP class](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/2542.htm) to do this on a couple of occasions.  Solid results, GPL code, and easily deployed.  Recommended.