# How to convert UTM coordinates to Latitude and Longitude?

Tags: algorithm, gis, latitude-longitude

#### Duplicates:

- [How do I convert coordinates to a Latitude & Longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609379/)
- [How to convert from UTM to LatLng in python or Javascript2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343865/)

My current project is interfacing with a central geocoding service published by the local city planning department.  The service is designed primarily for surveying, and as such returns coordinates in a UTM X-Y format.  My system stores coordinates as decimal latitude and longitude for integration with Google Earth and other mapping tools.

I'd like to come up with an algorithm for converting from X-Y to latitude and longitude for all cases.  I have not been able to locate any texts describing the conversion; the most I've been able to find via Google is raw source code in the form of Excel Visual Basic and FORTRAN.  I believe a useful general solution would be beneficial to the community at large.

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609379/how-do-i-convert-coordinates-to-a-latitude-longitude

Comment: Or maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343865/how-to-convert-from-utm-to-latlng-in-python-or-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a map projection library to do this.

There are many libraries available that are open source.  One of the most complete is [PROJ.4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/).

It is wrapped and used internally by many simpler libraries, such as [GDAL](http://gdal.org/).

This will allow you to go from UTM->LatLon (with many options), UTM->State Plane, or from any common projection to any other common projection.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, I would use the [OpenMap converter](http://openmap.bbn.com/doc/api/com/bbn/openmap/proj/coords/UTMPoint.html#toLatLonPoint()) from a point's expression in UTM to one using Latitude and Longitude (assuming a WGS-84 ellipsoid which is most commonly used in GPS).

OpenMap is open source and I would post a link to their download page but they have a short license script in the way.  So, to avoid being rude, I won't deep link.  Instead, head to [their homepage](http://openmap.bbn.com/) and [click Downloads](http://openmap.bbn.com/cgi-bin/license.cgi).

That should either solve your problem directly or at least point you towards a useful algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

you could try https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/home (Was: http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite/ which is now broken).